# How to create predictive model using Naive Bayes in Python?

Tags: python, naivebayes

It's my first time using python and I have created a basic [csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wm7YPhWH-JvlgVvpepr9FtChTJKPgysg/view?usp=sharing) file. I want to know how would you create a predictive model using Naive Bayes to classify if the words are informative or uninformative ?

Answer (score 1):

Python has a very extensive machine learning library [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/).

As you are new to AI with python, you should consider learning from the [basics](https://www.kaggle.com/learn/intro-to-machine-learning). If you have already, [DataCamp's Naive Bayes guide](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/naive-bayes-scikit-learn) would be a good resource you can follow to achieve the classification model you want.